# Protocol method not being recognized when called via delegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, protocols

My problem is that when I am calling the protocol method `dataLoading` via the delegate, it just doesn't recognize it - giving an `expected identifier` error.

Here is the protocol/interface file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class LoaderView;

@protocol DataLoaderProtocol <NSObject>

@required
- (void) dataLoading;
- (void) doneLoading;

@end

@interface DataLoader : NSObject {

}

@property (retain) id <DataLoaderProtocol> delegate;
@property (retain, nonatomic) LoaderView *loader;

- (id) initWithDelegate: (id <DataLoaderProtocol>) delegate;
- (void) start;

@end
```

And here is the implementation file:

```
#import "DataLoader.h"
#import "LoaderView.h"


@implementation DataLoader

@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
@synthesize loader = _loader;

- (id) initWithDelegate: (id <DataLoaderProtocol>) delegate
{
    self.delegate = delegate;

    return self;
}

- (void) start
{
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];
    NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] 
                                        initWithTarget:self.delegate
                                        selector:@selector([self.delegate dataLoading]) 
                                        object:nil];
    [queue addOperation:operation]; 
    [operation release];
}

@end
```

The error is at this line: `selector:@selector([self.delegate dataLoading])`

I'm sure this is a stupid mistake on my part, but I don't understand why it's not recognizing that method, since the delegate is tied in with the protocol...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you wrote `selector:@selector([self.delegate dataLoading])` is wrong try using : `selector:@selector(dataLoading)` instead.

Comment: Doh!! Yea you're right, because I already specified the target! What a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if `self` is defined yet when you call `initWithDelegate`.  That may be messing up things downstream...

Try:

```
- (id) initWithDelegate: (id <DataLoaderProtocol>) delegate {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        self.delegate = delegate
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: right, and don't we need to make a direct assignement too ? `delegate = [aDelegate retain];`

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a selector (i.e. `SEL` type), therefore you would need to write this:

```
NSInvocationOperation *operation = 
    [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] 
        initWithTarget:self.delegate
              selector:@selector(dataLoading) // the name of the selector here 
                object:nil];
```